# Proper use of shimano chain measuring tool

Tags: shimano

I bought a [TL-CN42](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/shimano/WP-Y12160000.html).  The instructions are vague.  I inserted the double toothed end between 2 rivets.  The single toothed end then rests on another rivet, BUT if I push down lightly, it will go between rivets.  Is it time to replace?  This is a 9.5 month old, 10 cog cassette, touring bike with about 2,700 miles, 95% on roads or paved trails.

Comment: That is a nice chain-checker. I added one to my tool box about ten years ago.  It is my go-to for a quick check on my chain. Granted I still always also check with a metal tape measure before committing to a chain replacement, but other Shimano tool is solid.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this PDF I found](https://www.cycling-parts.ch/images/pdf/shimano-tl-cn42.pdf) it seems that your chain still has life left in it.  It's when the ping drops between the pins that your chain has stretched too much.

This is pretty good: 2700mi is about 4400km which is approaching the expected lifespan of a chain (5000km).  I've had decent chains which haven't lasted nearly that long. 
 (Admittedly I do occasionally ride in wet weather.)

(Apologies for getting this messed up earlier.)

Comment: For all chain tools I've used in the past a 'single ping not dropping between the rivets' is an indication of the chain being fine and NOT worn (enough to replace it). Is the Shimano chain tool different?
(I agree that 2700mi is not bad for a chain)

Comment: @TerrySeidler You're right; I messed that up.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks. Those pictograms came wih the package, but I thought the bottom right picture in graphic 2 meant don't measure the chain when it is slack. Apparently, it means, don't push down.